# Getting invalid syntax error when starting Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am using python3.7. the jupyter notebook seems to be importing 
asynico and this is leading to a syntax error. I cant seem to wrap my head around why..
[image]

Comment: I am on a conda enviornment using python 3.7.4

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the problem seems to be; when Jupyter notebook try to load, it's sub-modules trys to import asyncio. But when importing asyncio, syntax error is rasied. What should I do?

Comment: Try finding that file in your computer and seeing what comes on the line before the error, or try reinstalling your environment. The file might have becomes mangled somehow.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I manually went and replaced asyncio file in the site-package folder with the newer version from github.